# Send Parameter When Redirecting to a new page

Tags: asp.net, parameters

I get a userId in the Default page, where I connect to the database(Oracle if it's interesting).I want to keep this userId and use it in the pages I open. I need it to compare with a combobox SelectedItem.Value. And this combobox is found almost in all the pages in the web site.How can I send this UserId as a parameter? Or is there a place where I can keep this variable and use it when I need. I'm sure it's very common and I wonder what the common and best way is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it as a `querystring parameter`, but the best way to keep the value in memory is with a [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) variable

Answer (score 2):

Have a look @

[ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

AND

[ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) would be a good place for a variable like a UserID.

Answer (score 1):

If you're needing it in (almost) every page, I think `Session` would be a good place to put the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) on msdn

[How to Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways:

One, you can simply put it in the session and use it everywhere for the user session.

Second, you can pass it explicitly using a post or querystring. Using this option will need you to specify it all redirections.

Answer (score 1):

As others said you can store variables in Session. But if you want to save information about user "Microsoft way", best is to implement [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) classes.